# Want to add up values in specific column in ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my angular project, the user can select an employee from a combobox. Then, using an ngFor, the data from only that user is displayed in a table. One of the columns is hours and in the table footer, I want to be able to add up the number of hours that each employee has for each of the selected types. Below is the function that I've tried but it just gets the total hours for all of the employees. How would I filter it out so that it would only be for the selected employee?

Here's my function:

```
getTotalPtoRequests() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.ptoData.length; i++) {
        if (this.ptoData[i].hours) {
            this.totalPtoRequests += this.ptoData[i].hours;
        }
    }
    return this.totalPtoRequests;
}
```

and here's where it's called:

```
    <span class="requestText">PTO Requests: {{getTotalPtoRequests()}} hours / {{getTotalPtoRequests()/8}} day(s)</span>
```

here are my full .ts and .html files for reference:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info';
import { TrackerComponent } from './tracker.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-grid',
    templateUrl: `./grid.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})

export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    newRow: PTOData = new PTOData();
    totalPtoRequests: number = 0;
    totalEtoRequests: number = 0;


    @Input() selectedEmployee: number;
    @Input() selectedType: string;

    @Output() notify = new EventEmitter<number>();

    rowSelected: number;

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => {
                this.empInfo = empInfo.sort((a, b) =>
                    a.LastName < b.LastName ? -1 : b.LastName < a.LastName ? 1 : 0);
            });
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => {
                this.ptoData = ptoData.sort((a, b) =>
                    a.date < b.date ? -1 : b.date < a.date ? 1 : 0);
            });
    }
        nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee + 1;
        this.notify.emit(this.selectedEmployee);
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee - 1;
        this.notify.emit(this.selectedEmployee);
    }

    firstEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = 0;
        this.notify.emit(this.selectedEmployee);
    }

    lastEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.empInfo.length - 1;
        this.notify.emit(this.selectedEmployee);
    }
    
    getTotalPtoRequests() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.ptoData.length; i++) {
            if (this.ptoData[i].hours) {
                this.totalPtoRequests += this.ptoData[i].hours;
            }
        }
        return this.totalPtoRequests;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" *ngIf="empInfo && empInfo.length > selectedEmployee">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Full/Half</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Scheduled?</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
      <th>In P/R?</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
        <span class="requestText">PTO Requests: {{getTotalPtoRequests()}} hours / {{getTotalPtoRequests()/8}} day(s)</span>
        <span class="requestText"> | </span>
        <span class="requestText">ETO Requests: {{empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORequests}} hours / {{empInfo[selectedEmployee].ETORequests/8}} day(s)</span>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-bargin" style="float: right;" (click)="lastEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <button [disabled]="!isPreviousValid()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float:right;" (click)="nextEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <div class="footertext">{{selectedEmployee+1}} of {{empInfo.length}}</div>
        <button [disabled]="!isNextValid()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float: right;" (click)="previousEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-flip-horizontal fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-margin" style="float: right;" (click)="firstEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-step-backward fa-lrg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let pto of (ptoData | currentEmployee:empInfo[selectedEmployee].EmpKey); let i = index">
      <ng-container [ngSwitch]="isRowSelected(i)">
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">
          <ng-container *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType">
            <tr pto-row-display [pto]="pto" (click)="selectRow(i)"></tr>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="true">
          <tr pto-row-edit [pto]="pto" [rowSelected]="rowSelected" (onSave)="onSave($event)" (onDelete)="onDelete($event)" *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType"></tr>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update with code for selecting the employee:

```html
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
          <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="PTOtype" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
          <option selected="selected" value="PTO">PTO</option>
          <option value="etoEarned">ETO - Earned</option>
          <option value="etoUsed">ETO - Used</option>
          <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
          <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
        </select> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <pto-grid [selectedType]="selectedType" [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee" (notify)="onNotify($event)"></pto-grid>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an `updateTotals` function to my get function that looked like this:

```
updateTotals() {
    if (this.empInfo) {
        this.totalPtoRequests = 0;
        this.totalEtoRequests = 0;
        let temp = this.ptoData.filter(p => p.EmpKey == this.empInfo[this.selectedEmployee].EmpKey);
        for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i].type == 'PTO') {
                this.totalPtoRequests += temp[i].hours;
            } else if (temp[i].type == 'etoUsed') {
                this.totalEtoRequests += temp[i].hours;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then also added in ngOnChanges to watch for when the selected employee changes that looks like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: { [propKey: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    for (let propName in changes) {
        if (propName == "selectedEmployee") {
            this.updateTotals();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could you aggregate the hours when a user is selected, then store that value in totalPTORequests and output to the html

```
<span class="requestText">PTO Requests: {{totalPTORequests}} hours / {{totalPTORequests/8}} day(s)</span>
```

then everytime a new user is selected that aggregate function is run again -> totalPTORequests value is updated -> your table footer is updated

Comment: how would I aggregate the hours though? that's the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: is there an event that is triggered when a user is selected? and if so does that event have access to the selected row's data?

Comment: the user is selected in a different component and then the selected user is passed to the component where the data is displayed. I'm updating my OP with the code for that

Comment: alright, If I am tracking correctly, you could add the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook in your pto-grid component. So everytime a new selectedEmployee index is passed in you would aggregate that employees hours.